# How to upgrade 3.x code to 6.3.0 since it is missing FontKey and PdfFont

Tags: java, jasper-reports, migration

We have migrated to Java 8 and we need to move from v3.5.2 of JasperReports jar to v6.3.0.

In the code we are using `FontKey` and `PdfFont` classes, which do not seem to present in the updated jar. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both where first deprecated (I saw them last in version 5.5.1) and are now removed from JasperReports library.

The solution is to revert back to 5.5.1 or even better to **not** use them anymore, change your code accordingly. The documentation points to [FontFamily.getExportFont(java.lang.String)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fonts/FontFamily.html#getExportFont(java.lang.String)).

> **Note:** In newer versions of jasper-reports
>   you should use [font-extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/), to include and display correctly fonts when exporting to pdf.